# How to pass selected items data to another component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Menu component, which displays my Menu items. I also have here function `addToCart` and Cart icon. Function `addToCart` works fine and store array of selected items.

```
const Menu = () => {

  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const addToCart = (el) => setCart( [...cart, el]);
  console.log(cart);

  return (
    <>
      <Tabs className="tabs-wrapper" id="menu">
      <TabList className="tabs">
        <Tab className="tab-item">Burgers</Tab>
        <Tab className="tab-item">Lunch of the day</Tab>
        <Tab className="tab-item">Crepes</Tab>
      </TabList>
      <TabPanel>
        <div className="burgers">
          <ul> 
          {burgers.map(burger => (
            <li key={burger.id}>
            <h4>{burger.title}</h4>
            <span>{burger.price}</span>
            <img src={burger.image} alt={burger.title} />
            <p>{burger.description}</p>
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart(burger.title, "burger")}>Add to cart</button>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>
      <div className="crepes">
          <ul>
          {crepes.map(crepe => (
            <li key={crepe.id}>
              <h4>{crepe.title}</h4>
              <span>{crepe.price}</span>
              <img src={crepe.image} alt={crepe.title} />
              <p>{crepe.description}</p>
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart(crepe.title, "crepe")}>Add to cart</button>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
    </Tabs>
    <FontAwesomeIcon className="cart" icon={["fas", "shopping-cart"]}/>
  </>
  )
}
```

How to pass these items info to Cart component, which I want to open on Cart icon click? Also I would like to avoid router if it's possible.

**Edit:**

How to make Cart component show `image`,`title` and `price` properties of items, added to a Cart?

```
const Cart = (props) => {

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <img src={props.image} alt={props.title} />
        <h4>{props.title}</h4>
        <span>{props.price}</span>
      </div>
      <Form/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `cart` with other props to CartComponent.

```
<CartComponent cart={ cart }/>
```

If your CartCompoennt is outside menu you should bring your cart state up in that way to by able pass them where you need.

```
function App() {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    const addToCart = (el) => setCart( [...cart, el]);

    return (
        <div>
              <CartComponent cart={ cart }/>
              <Menu cart={ cart } addToCart={ addToCart } />
        </div>
    )
}
```